# Unable to open Microsoft Office files in Office client from SharePoint online 2013

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have SharePoint online 2013 site which displays the reports for different departments. All departments have different groups and they have assigned permission that way so one group can not see other group files. I am using JAVA SCRIPT and AJAX to get the files from gallery. when I use JavaScript on my page I am unable to open the documents in client application, it opens in office online than users have to download. IS there anyway user can click on it and it will download the files. I went to library setting and changed the default to open in client application also changed in site collection and features but still SharePoint opens the file in online instead of client application. We are using office 2010 and SharePoint online 2013.

```
(function () { 


    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var galleryContext = {}; 
    galleryContext.Templates = {}; 


    galleryContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='gallery'>"; 
    galleryContext.Templates.Footer = "</div><div class='gallerydocs'></div>"; 


    // This line of code tell TemplateManager that we want to change all HTML for item row render 
    galleryContext.Templates.Item = galleryTemplate; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(galleryContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic 
function galleryTemplate(ctx) { 
    var icon = ctx.CurrentItem["GalleryIcon"];
    var src =  ctx.CurrentItem["FileRef"];
    var name = ctx.CurrentItem["Title"];
    var subtitle =ctx.CurrentItem["SubTitle"];
    var bgcolor = ctx.CurrentItem["BackgroundColor"];
    var fontcolor = ctx.CurrentItem["FontColor"];

    //var description = ctx.CurrentItem["Description"]; 
// console.log(JSON.stringify(ctx.CurrentItem["GalleryIcon"]));
    // Return whole item html 
    return "<div onclick='javascript:getGalleryDocs("+'"'+  src + '"' +", "+'"'+  bgcolor + '"' +", "+'"'+  subtitle + '"' +", "+'"'+  fontcolor + '"' +", "+'"'+  name + '"' +" )'><div class='galleryblock' style='background-color:" + bgcolor + ";color:"+ fontcolor+"' >"+name +"<br/><br/><p>"+subtitle +"</p></div></div>"; 
} 


function getGalleryDocs(folder , bgcolor, subtitle ,fontcolor  , name)
{

$.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('"+folder+"')/files?$orderby=Title",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
        var html="<div class='gallerynav'><span><a href='javascript:goback();'>BILLING REPORTS</a><span> <i class='fa fa-caret-right' ></i><span>"+name+"</span></div><div class='galleryblock' style='float:none;background-color:" + bgcolor + ";color:"+ fontcolor+"' >"+name +"<br/><br/><p>"+subtitle +"</p></div><span></span>";
        var results = data.d.results;
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(results.length));
        html+= "<ul class='gallerylinks'>";
        if(results.length > 0)
        {
            for( i=0 ; i< results.length ; i++)
            {
                var item = results[i];
                html+= "<li><a href='" + item.LinkingUrl + "' target='_blank'>"+item.Title+"&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class='fa fa-external-link'></i></a></li>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            html+="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;THERE ARE NO DOCUMENTS IN THIS GALLERY"
        }
        html+="<ul>"
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        $(".gallery").hide(500);
        $(".gallerydocs").html(html);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $(".gallerydocs").html("You dont have permissions to view this folder!")
        }
        });
}
function goback(){
$(".gallery").show(500);
        $(".gallerydocs").html("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not got an environment to hand to test this on but it will be something to do with your href link. It's needs to be built differently. The solution below hopefully will open in the clients application.

Try

```
    <a href=""
    onclick="editDocumentWithProgID2('http://server/site/doclib/folder/Document.docx', 
    '', 
    'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', '0', 
    'http://server/site', '0')">
    This will open the file in edit mode
</a>
```

A full post can be found [here](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/09/29/open-sharepoint-files-in-edit-mode-from-client-applications-and-not-read-only/)

[THis](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/90c1b767-5f13-452f-9048-11dc06674f26/download-file-from-document-library-by-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) post offers a solution to directly download

Sorry I can't test

Good luck

Cheers
Truez

Comment: What if I want them to open as read only or download on their own desktop and they can make change which will not affect to master file stored on SharePoint.

Comment: Check the second link for information on how to download the file, Once again it's just a small tweak to your HTML.